# GetElementById не выводится

Tags: javascript

Подскажите новичку, почему этот код не отрабатывает, точнее в `qq.innerHTML` выводится `fhfhf[object HTMLDivElement]`, а не число?

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
  function ok(){
   var x = document.getElementById('q2')
   qq.innerHTML = "fhfhf" + x;
  }
  </script>
 </head>
<body>

<center>
<div id="q2" name="q2">50</div>
<div id="qq"></div>
<input type="button" name="pl" id="pl" onclick="ok()">
</center>
</body>
```

Comment: а вы не забыли эту строчку дописать?
`var qq = document.getElementById('qq')`

Comment: @MasterAlex  ничего не поменялось...

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, ничего не поменялось, потому что нужно было ещё решить проблему ниже, но без этой строчки тоже работать не будет, как минимум в фаерфоксе  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что в переменную **x** записывается ссылка на элемент, а не его значение.
Чтобы всё заработало, нужно извлечь значение по этой ссылке:

```
var x = document.getElementById('q2').innerHTML;
```

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @Safort подскажите, http://jsfiddle.net/toLfoo3f/ 
я нажимаю на кнопку и отражается число 49, при нажатии второй раз,  уже ничего не меняется, прошу только подсказать, как сделать так что бы число уменьшалось каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку на 1?

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, потому что qq не определено было http://jsfiddle.net/kLpm1f4e/

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, как выше сказал @stck, это из-за того, что переменная qq не была определена. 
Вот чуть более сокращённый вариант http://jsfiddle.net/kLpm1f4e/1/
Но вообще, все переменные всегда нужно объявлять через var, иначе потом проблем не оберёшься.

Comment: @Safort, можно и ещё короче, работает в хроме: http://jsfiddle.net/kLpm1f4e/2/

Comment: @MasterAlex, можно и еще короче: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnwovu0p/ (Chrome, Firefox)